# What is the least dense rigid periodic circle packing of uniform coordination?

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, packing-problem

> **Question:** What is the least dense rigid periodic circle packing of uniform coordination?
>
> **In other words:** Using congruent circles, how sparse can a rigid ***and*** periodic packing (where each circle touches the same number of other circles) be made?

Here is some clarification on the terminology:

- By **"congruent"** I mean identical.
- By **"how sparse"** I mean the rarest possible circle packing.
- By **"rigid"** I mean a packing in which no circle can be moved without moving other circles. Maybe the word stable would have been better. Sorry about that.
- By **"uniform coordination"** I mean a packing where each circle is in contact with $n$ other circles.

The packing has to be finite since I asked for a periodic packing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not clear at all ! What do you mean by "large, dense, rigid, uniform coordination" ? Moreover, do you consider a finite of infinite packing like in the first figure [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html) ?

Comment: Could you answer our questions ?

Comment: Could you edit the post to include some motivation for why you asked this question and why it interests you? Please also include any attempts of your own to answer the question if possible.